# Android Maps API V2 Doesn't show map only the plus and minus button

Tags: android, maps

I've tried the others suggestion but no luck. I've change the API Key many times already.

Heres the code for my MapActivity.java

```
package com.santehfeedsgis;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
 }

}
```

for my layout activity_map.xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the code for the manifest AndroidManifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.santehfeedsgis"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission 
    android:name="com.santehfeedsgis.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.santehfeedsgis.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>    
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="mysecretkeyhere/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.santehfeedsgis.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: can you post your xml layout code. also does your app crash?

Comment: did u try the below does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh I Finally found the answer by going to Eclipse WINDOW>Preferences>Android>Build and used the SHA1 that is generated there. :D

Comment: worked without changing `SupportMapFragment` to `MapFragment`?

Comment: yes it worked without changing I change the minimum sdk to 8 also to support lower units

Answer (score 1):

Your min sdk is 12. Extend standard `Activity`. You can use `MapFragment`

```
   <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Also make sure you have enabled maps for andorid in google api console and make sure you have followed all steps in the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

**If your min sdk is 11 and below you need to use `SupportMapFragment` in which case you need to extend `FragmentActivtiy`.**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. This Link is for Google Map with-in Fragments

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=pl#using_xml_attributes.

Best Of Luck.